# Detect Junk Characters in string

Tags: c#, string

I want to allow user to enter characters,numbers and special characters but no the JUNK Characters (ex. ♠ ♣ etc) whose ascii value is greater thane 127.

I have function like this

```
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) // value is input string
            {
                if ((int)value[i] < 32 || (int)value[i] > 126)
                {

                         // show error

                 }

            }
```

This makes code bit slower as i have to compare each and every string and its character.
Can anyone suggest better approach ?

Comment: Unless you have some really huge strings this code should be pretty fast. I wouldn't expect any performance problems with it.

Comment: This might be a good place to use Regex or LINQ.

Comment: @Tim, a `for` loop would be the fastest. If it is not fast enough for the OP a Regex would be even worse.

Comment: @Darin - Is that because the Regex or a LINQ expression would have to do some sort of iteration over the string as well - which would be slower than just a straight for loop?

Comment: @Tim, yeap, it is because of that.

Comment: @Tim If speed is your objective, rarely LINQ is your solution.

Comment: @xanatos: I disagree: using LINQ lets your write very readable code all through your code base, which means you can then analyze where the bottlenecks occur and micro-optimize *just those bits* if necessary. In many cases the simplicity of LINQ actually lets you express a more efficient solution than you'd write by hand, simply because it's easy to do so. Hand-coding the efficient solution could end up being just too complex.

Comment: @Jon I DO love LINQ because it's (normally) easily readable, but if someone asks me "what is the fastest solution to a micro-problem", rarely it's LINQ. LINQ is the fastest to write and to maintain. The OP asked for a solution that is written in 3 lines of code. I can maintain 3 lines of code even without LINQ. And yes, what you wrote is absolutely correct, but I'm not sure that what you wrote is in disagreement with what I wrote :-) I wrote "the part that must be super-fast rarely can be written in LINQ". You wrote "but everything else can"

Comment: @Sangram What you wrote is probably the fastest method. Only thing: You don't need to cast to int.

Comment: @xanatos: It depends what you're doing. I find that LINQ can help me reduce the big-oh complexity of a problem more than I would want to by hand - so a constant factor becomes irrelevant. But I think you missed my bigger point - that if speed of your overall application is your objective, LINQ is a great solution, because it helps you find the hotspots easily by keeping the code simple. Those hotspots *may* be improved by micro-optimization, but just as often they can be fixed more effectively by redesign. There's more to the objective of speed than micro-optimization.

Comment: @Jon No, I see you point and I think the same thing. LINQ is easier to maintain, so you have more time to optimize, and less code that need optimization (so the haystack where to search the needle is smaller). My sentence was about the last method, not the overall procedure. In the same way once upon a time you wouldn't write 100% of a program in ASM but you would write 99% in C and 1% in ASM, it's better to write 99% in LINQ and 1% optimize unwinding the LINQ.

Comment: @xanatos: Exactly... although it's also worth bearing in mind the point that the micro-optimization may be unnecessary when you have clearer sight of the bigger picture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, for one thing you can make the code *simpler*:

```
foreach (char c in value)
{
    if (c < 32 || c > 126)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or using LINQ, if you just need to know if *any* characters are non-ASCII:

```
bool bad = value.Any(c => c < 32 || c > 126);
```

... but fundamentally you're not going to be able to detect non-ASCII characters without iterating over every character in the string...

Comment: Any thing like Try parse method? like we do for decimal or int

Comment: Isn't there `char.IsLetter` method?

Comment: John: what can be d fastest approach ? Linq or Loop.i guess LINQ..what u suggest ?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, char.IsLetter returns false for numbers, so it is not equivalent to the original test case interval (32, 126).

Comment: @Sangram: LINQ is just going to loop internally. Just how much text are you testing? It should be extremely fast...

Comment: string will not be greater than 15.But i have got lots of strings to be tested & i need to test them separately. Another point i would like to add is if it finds JUNK in the first letter will it go till the last letter to check or will stop after finding 1st letter? If it can stop after finding 1st character it will boost its perfomnce.

Comment: @Sangram: `Any()` will stop at the first match. You can easily break out of the `foreach` loop in a similar way. But just how many strings *do* you have to be tested? Have you actually tried any of this and found that it's too expensive? Or are you just guessing?

Comment: @John:No. of string should be around 30,000 + and i have put timer while testing i noticed that this thing is taking time. The ANY approach is awesome and it will certainly make my code efficient.

Comment: @Sangram: 30,000 strings of 15 characters should take hardly any time at all. You say you've "noticed that this thing is taking time" - how much time? Are you running under a debugger?

Comment: JOHN: seems like i have confused you.Sorry for that.I have series of functions executing in my code, above mentioned function was taking more time as compared to the other functions. So i thought it will be better if i can avoid the loops and could implement method like try parse. After your answer I was not sure if the LINQ is faster or not.AS you have said LINQ does same internally what 'FOR' loop does so that means there wont be much difference between what i was doing earlier. Right ?

Comment: @Sangram: Right. (Actually, it'll use the string iterator rather than repeatedly using the indexer - I don't know whether that will be faster or slower.) But it's cleaner code, which is usually what's more important. Have you actually determined that this code is *too slow* or just *slower than some other code*? There's a huge difference.

Comment: I just thought its SLOW because of its iterations. And you are Right There is huge difference. I will have to test both codes on Large no. of strings to actually check which one is faster.But i am glad that i have learned some good things[Any()] today from you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can make regular expression which allowed all the desired characters and use it for each strings. I think this will improve the performance. All you have to do is to create a proper regular expression.

**Update:** However, Using RegEx will not improve the speed it will just minimize the code lines.

Comment: Why should a Regex be faster than C# code? The Regex won't transform a O(n) problem to a O(1) problem.

Comment: Agreed. But it minimizes (I think almost 20%) the time to compare the character binaries (plus converting it to int) since it is being pre-compiled.

Comment: Not in my world. Regex is 5-10 TIMES slower than for in Release+NoDebug (http://pastebin.com/w85vYRpv )

Comment: @xanatos; I agreed with the result of the codes. Till now I was in a different world. Thank you for making efforts to convince me.