# How to validate the garbage value returned by Bouncy Castle rsa decryption with wrong key

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle

I am looking for a reliable way to validate if the string which is returned after decrypting the encrypted payload is a garbage value (like: �=z�{���Z���:���k/����˃�d�A��*�Ԥ�= �?M����5).
I am trying to decrypt the encrypted string with a different public key so, as expected, I am getting a garbage string like posted above. My question is, what is the best way to validate in c# whether the string returned is a valid string or some garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer by Jon Skeet here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7254261/2858235

```
foreach (char c in value)
{
    if (c < 32 || c > 126)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you propose will only check if the returned string is ASCII (technically a subset of ASCII)... Considering your name and your surname, you should have first hand knowledge that the world isn't made of ASCII strings. Unicode was "invented" for a reason. Now, as written [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/136437/encryption-and-data-integrity), RSA is "malleable". A very simple solution is to append/prepend the hash of the original text (for example using SHA256) to the text before encrypting everything and then verify if the hash is correct after decryption.

Comment: I agree that it would be a cleaner way but since in my scenario, it will require a client side change (because they are encrypting the string and I am decrypting it in server side code), I will have to go with my solution. Also, I think it would be okay if I consider only that "subset" of ASCII since I am expecting my string to have only those characters.

Comment: btw, just curious, what is wrong with my name and surname. In English, It falls inside that subset of ASCII characters right? :)

Comment: @AshishAgrawal Probably half the american programmers think that all the alphabet is contained in the A-Z character set... They can't even imagine that other languages could need non-ASCII characters like àèéìòù (without even thinking about Chinese, Japanese, the various Indian languages...)... You can see this in every Regex question ("how can I check if it is a word? Use something like `[A-Za-z]*`. Given your name, you should be (or your parents should be) from a part of the world where `A-Z` isn't your native character set.

Comment: gotcha. thanks for the explanation. That makes me realize that I should check if we have any non English speaking customers because the string I am encrypting/decrypting contains the user name of the users. and the validation will fail in case if they have some other (than the subset I am relying on) characters in their names. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned with RSA alone, use a proper padding scheme like [Optimal Asymmetric Encryption Padding (OAEP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) as defined in PKCS#1 v2.0. It uses hashing internally to check if there are errors. C# has native support for that and you will get an error if something wrong happened like a broken ciphertext or the wrong key were used.

If you're concerned with [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) (RSA + some block cipher), I suggest that you use RSA-OAEP along with an authenticated mode of operation such as [AES-GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) (available in C# through BouncyCastle). That way, you can determine all (malicious) manipulations.